# How does UIImage decides it's scale size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, afnetworking-2

I am using `AFNetworking 2.0` category on `UIImageView` to download images.

```
po imgReceived.scale
```

gives me 1 some times 2. How is that? By any chance there stands a possibility that `UIImage` scale is same as `UIScreen` scale. I shouldn't be.

So.. 
What is `UIImage` scale when `imagedata` is coming from server side. Who and What decides that scale ?

Answer (score 1):

**From the Documentation:**

> The scale factor of the image is (read-only)
>
> If you load an image from a file whose name includes the @2x modifier,
>   the scale is set to 2.0. You can also specify an explicit scale factor
>   when initializing an image from a Core Graphics image. All other
>   images are assumed to have a scale factor of 1.0.

If you multiply the logical size of the image (stored in the size property) by the value in this property, you get the dimensions of the image in pixels.

In your case, as imagedata is getting from server, and once you get the data:

if you are creating an image by using the method:

```
 - (nullable instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data;
```

the image scale factor is set based on the image size

and if you are using this method:

```
 - (nullable instancetype)initWithData:(NSData *)data scale:(CGFloat)scale NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
```

then you can specify the scale factor for the image you are creating.

> Applying a scale factor of 1.0 results in an image whose size matches
>   the pixel-based dimensions of the image. Applying a different scale
>   factor changes the size of the image as reported by the size property.